# compare dates with time in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

I want to find which one is greater from 2 dates with time that is in the following format in javascript

date1=2-11-2012 13:40:00
date2=01-11-2012 10:40:00

Comment: @Pragnesh Chauhan on 6 questions!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hopefully you can learn something...

- Create `Date` objects using the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor.
- Understand how comparison operator internally calls [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf), and [what that means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) for a `Date` object.
- Understand how [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) work (e.g. `>`).
- Understand conditions and their [Boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) outputs.

Then, you may come up with something like...

```
var isLarger = new Date("2-11-2012 13:40:00") > new Date("01-11-2012 10:40:00");
```

Comment: correct answer, but is the `+` before those dates necessary? i think you can compare Date objects directly.

Comment: @Chips_100 I was confused for when you need them. The comparison operator seems to call their `valueOf()` implicitly.

Comment: new Date("2-11-2012 13:40:00") will give an invalid date object and +new Date("2-11-2012 13:40:00") will give NaN. How they can be compared?

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli [It doesn't give me an invalid date](http://cl.ly/image/3o2f1a0P1v12).

Comment: @alex [Check This](http://twitpic.com/b9k7p7)

Comment: new Date("2-11-2012 13:40:00") > new Date("01-12-2012 10:40:00"); this is also giving "true" only.  so its not working

Comment: @albertJegani If you look at the dates in those objects, you can see that the first one is 11th Feb 2012 and the second is 12th Jan 2012, so the comparison *is* correct. Your expectations at how the string would be parsed is incorrect.

Comment: yes  alex, its correct

Answer (score 1):

```
var x=new Date();
x.setFullYear(2100,0,14);
var y=new Date();
y.setFullYear(2100,0,20);

if (x>y)
{
 alert("Message1");
}
else
{
alert("Message2");
}
```

Comment: The question is of comparing two given dates. not a particular date with today. Please improve your answer.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli, Like x you can go for another y.

Comment: +1 I know that. Now it is perfect.